# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: main.wordlist Error

Tags: python

I am basically trying to create a new database and enter the database values according to the following:

```
 def createindextables(self):
    self.con.execute('create table urllist(url)')
    self.con.execute('create table worldlist(word)')
    self.con.execute('create table wordlocation(urlid,wordid,location)')
    self.con.execute('create table link(fromid integer,toid integer)')
    self.con.execute('create table linkwords(wordid,linkid)')
    self.con.execute('create index wordidx on wordlist(word)')
    self.con.execute('create index urlidx on urllist(url)')
    self.con.execute('create index wordurlidx on wordlocation(wordid)')
    self.con.execute('create index urltoidx on link(toid)')
    self.con.execute('create index urlfromidx on link(fromid)')
    self.dbcommit()
```

But while running it "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: main.wordlist Error" is coming up. I am not sure why its not able to detect the search database. It should at least run from the live compiler. I don't know why its not working properly. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might by a typo: is `worldlist` supposed to be `wordlist`?:
If so, change the second line to:

```
self.con.execute('create table wordlist(word)')
```

(Otherwise, the line

```
self.con.execute('create index wordidx on wordlist(word)')
```

might be raising an error since `wordlist` had not been defined.

---

Just as a sanity check, you might try running

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('create table urllist(url)')
cursor.execute('create table wordlist(word)')
```

This code should work. You might then try comparing what's different about this code than yours.

Comment: Thats what i thought initially but i tried all ways of improving it, it didn't really work out. I am out of options at the moment